# CS-Cart: Showing Store Closed Screen

Tags: php, cs-cart

I am setting up my client's CS-Cart eCommerce site on my local development machine. I have imported the database dump or SQL file and used database connection details correctly in `config.local.php` but I am consistently getting "Store Closed" screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to uncomment this line of  code   `define('DEVELOPMENT', true);` first ,that's how you can see the error.Try this first and then send me exact error.

Comment: Thanks for helping me with it. It is now showing me the errors.